# How to order by number of rows of another table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have these two tables and I want to order by number of rows the second table has...I want a query to show me the **postid** and the **count()** comments of each postid...The above query that I have is working perfect but I want to add in query and the table posts just I need posts table to select * ...for another job...but it has to be on the same query... My problem is when I add and the posts table to the above query it multiplies the **count()** by 8 i.e. in how many fields there are in posts table... it can do his job and like this but I don't know if it's correct like that or not, or maybe there is and another way for that more simpler or correct! Thanks in advance!

```
       comments                          posts
+---------+------------+       +---------+-----------------+
|  Name   |   Type     |       |  Name   |   Type          |
+---------+------------+       +---------+-----------------+
| id      |int(10) prim|  +----| postid  |  int(10) prim   |
| name    |varchar(128)|  |    | title   |  varchar(100)   |
| email   |varchar(255)|  |    | image   |  varchar(150)   |
| body    |   text     |  |    | video   |  varchar(200)   |
| postid  |   int(10)  |--+    | body    |     text        |
| dt      | timestamp  |       | author  |  varchar(50)    |
+---------+------------+       | postdate|   timestamp     |
                               | category|enum('1','2','3')| 
                               +---------+-----------------+



    <?php       
    $sql = "SELECT comments.postid, count(*) FROM comments GROUP BY comments.postid ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 3";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    ?>

    Output of that query:   
    +--------+----------+ 
    | postid | count(*) |      
    +--------+----------+
    | 14     | 6        |
    | 13     | 4        | 
    | 15     | 3        | 
    +--------+----------+ 



    <?php       
    $sql = "SELECT comments.postid, count(*) FROM posts, comments GROUP BY comments.postid ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 3";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    ?>

    Output of that query:   
    +--------+----------+ 
    | postid | count(*) |      
    +--------+----------+
    | 14     | 48       |
    | 13     | 32       | 
    | 15     | 24       | 
    +--------+----------+
```

Comment: instead of count(*) have you tried count(distinct comments.id)? That may fix the multiplication issue.

Comment: OMG this was the solution...i don't believe it :P I am lot of hours with coding and i missed it pff ..thnks a lot!! If you want give it as an answer to approve it!